# Eclipse not opening browser when running application on glassfish server

Tags: java, eclipse, glassfish

I am running eclipse *Luna* with *glassfish 4.1*.

Everything seems to be running fine except when I use the option `"Run As/Run on Server"` the IDE does not open a browser to the context root of the application, like I would expect. *Glassfish* is started and the application deployed successfully but no browser is opened.

If I do the same to a *TomCat* server a browser is opened to the context root of the application. I can open a browser manually and type the URL and it works as expected but I would really like the time savings of this happening automatically.

Answer (score 3):

Inside your Eclipse, click in `"Window" -> Web Browser -> Choose your browser`.

Then right-click your project and run it.

Tested it with Eclipse Kepler, everything working correctly.

Comment: This did not help. The browser is already set and it works fine when I "Run on Server" to TomCat.

Answer (score 0):

Put file glassfish-web.xml in WEB-INF folder.

glassfish-web.xml content:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

   <!DOCTYPE glassfish-web-app PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1    Servlet 3.0//EN" "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-web-app_3_0-1.dtd">
  <glassfish-web-app>
  <context-root>/yourapp</context-root>
 </glassfish-web-app>
```

Comment: I am developing using JDK7 which does not require a glassfish-web.xml but I tried anyway, with no luck.

Comment: It's not depends from JDK, it's glassfish web application config. [Oracle Glassfish Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2417/beaql.html)

Comment: Correct but from JEE 1.6 the *web.xml is optional, the config can be specified with annotations. Either way I did try this with no luck. But thanks for you input.

Comment: Did you change "/yourapp" to your application name? What result? P.S. I used it in many projects with JDK6-7 and glassfish3-4 and it's "100% way".

Comment: I'm sorry, you were correct. This was the issue. Thanks so much for you help.

Answer (score 0):

Well I even reinstalled eclipse and the glassfish pluggin, to no avail. But it did discover I can open the browser to the root context from the Servers pain, by right clicking on the deployed application and selecting "Open in Browser". That works for me.